# REST service call which starts a workflow?

Tags: rest

We're building a web service and are trying to follow REST guidelines.  The service allows users to create and modify their account and the profile that goes along with it (think email preferences, addresses, etc.).

For the most part I think we've gotten things to a pretty clean point, however there's a use case where I'm unsure if the fit is right.

Supposed we have a call /password where the user can PUT a request that contains both their current and desired password.  This is fine, but we're trying to figure out an appropriate call to start the forgot password workflow, which kicks off some action on the server and the user gets instructions to their email on how to proceed.

Since the resources are supposed to be nouns and not verbs, adding a /forgotpassword somewhere in the URL doesn't make sense.  One approach we've been considering is using the same PUT as for the change password but with a different Content-Type / Accept header to differentiate the desired outcome.  I'm ok with this, but am wondering what some other options might be.

Comment: The title of your question is almost an oxymoron. Building a REST service with RPC is like building a circle with squares. Not impossible, but really counter-productive.

Comment: @PedroWerneck I'm not asking to build a REST service with RPC, I'm asking how something which in this case really is an action or workflow that must be started could be done while still following RESET principles.

Comment: Sure, I realized that, and that's why I'm the author of the answer below, but you should consider editing the title, since it doesn't reflect clearly what you're asking.

Comment: @PedroWerneck Changed, do you think its better now?

Comment: Much better. :) No doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a noun, how about a "password recovery" link relation which could serve as a collection under the user for recovery requests? A POST could kick off the workflow:

**Request**

```
POST /users/1/recovery-request
Content-Type: application/json

{
  email: "foo@bar.com",
  hint_question: 1,
  hint_answer: "MyMother'sMaidenName"
}
```

**Response**

```
204 No Content
```

This has the advantage of someone to be able to easily query the recovery collection to see how often you reset your password.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach is assuming that a DELETE request to your `/password` is a request to reset the password. It should return a 202 Accepted response, and a GET to it should signal this until the password reset workflow is completed or timed out.

The user shouldn't be doing a PUT request containing both the current and desired password, unless the `/password` representation returns their current and previous password. PUT is a complete replacement. If that password is the one users use to authenticate to your service, you should expect an Authorization header. If not, then you shouldn't be using PUT and make it a POST.

Comment: Using a DELETE seems rather bizarre.  In our case the existing password is not invalidated and a user never has to finish the workflow.  If the change password shouldn't contain the current one, how do you reasonably ensure the owner of the account is the one changing the password?  In almost all cases I've seen users must enter their current password before being allowed to change it, even if they just logged in 2 seconds ago.

Comment: That's why you should return a 202 Accepted, not a 200 OK or 204 No Content, as usual. You ensure the owner of the account is the one doing the operation by authenticating it through the Authorization header. If that's not possible, and these users aren't the same as the user of the API, then you should make it a POST, where you submit the information to a resource responsible for the reset operation.